# how to achieve this layout for iphone using CSS

Tags: iphone, css, webkit

[image: IF YOU RIGHT CLICK - VIEW IMAGE you will see it better]

-EDIT-

Well, i will update my question according to my progres wich you can see here: http://piscolabis.info/licht/job_single.html

My only problem now is that the background images are not seen in the iphone!!!

**HTML CODE**

```
<body class="job_single">

<div id="contenedor">
        <div id="head" class="section"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo_small.png" alt="lich-t" id="logo_small" /></a><h3><a href="locations.html"></a>JOBS</a></h3></div>
        <div id="contenido">
            <div id="panel" class="left">
                <div id="heading">
                    <h1>PRODUCER FEIHER / PRODUCER</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="information">
                    <p>Duselheimer habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam.</p>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="panel" class="right">
                <ul class="right visible">
                    <li id="pink">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span class="liLeft"></span>
                                                    <span class="liRight">
                                                        <h2>BENEDIKT / HOCKTE</h2>
                                                        <p>3D - Artist</p>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li id="orange">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span class="liLeft"></span>
                                                    <span class="liRight">
                                                        <h2>BEN SIEGLER</h2>
                                                        <p>Creative Director</p>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li id="blue">
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span class="liLeft"></span>
                                                    <span class="liRight">
                                                        <h2>ANDREAS FUS </h2>
                                                        <p>Asaberquépone</p>
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>  



</body>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.visible{display:block !important;position:relative;}

.job_single #panel.left,
.job_single #panel.right{
    margin-top:50px;
}

#panel.left{
        float:left;width:50%;
}

#panel.left #heading{
    float:left;
    background:#000;
    padding:20px;

        font-size:40px;
        line-height:40px;

}
#panel.left #information{
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
        background:url(../img/bg_black_alpha.png);
        font-size: 30px; line-height:30px;
        padding:20px;
}
#panel.left #information, #panel.left #heading{
        padding-left:30px;
        color:#fff;
}




#panel.right{
    width:40%;
    clear:none;
        float:right;
}
.job_single #panel.right ul.visible{margin-top:50px}

#panel.right ul.visible li{
    margin-top:20px;
}
#panel.right ul.visible li,#panel.right ul.visible li a{width:95%;height:90px;float:right;}

#panel.right ul.visible li a{
         background:black;
         border-right:10px solid yellow;
}

#panel.right ul.visible li a span.liLeft{
         width:95px;
         float:left;height:100%;display:block;
         position:relative;
         right:40px;
         -webkit-background-size: cover;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
         z-index:10;
}



#panel.right ul.visible li a span.liRight{
         background:black !important;
         color:#fff;

}

#panel.right ul.visible li a span.liRight{
        z-index:9;
}

#panel.right ul.visible li#blue a{
        border-color:#0C7CC3;
}
#panel.right ul.visible li#pink a{
        border-color:#C21B7B;
}
#panel.right ul.visible li#orange a{
        border-color:#E83B35;
}


#panel.right ul.visible li#blue a span.liLeft{
        background-image:url(../img/azul.png);
}
#panel.right ul.visible li#pink  a span.liLeft{
        background-image:url(../img/rosa.png);
}
#panel.right ul.visible li#orange  a span.liLeft{
        background-image:url(../img/naranja.png);
}


#panel.right ul.visible li a span.liRight h2{
         font-size:30px;
        margin-top:10px;
}

#panel.right ul.visible li a span.liRight p{
         font-size:30px;
         margin-top:5px;
}
```

Any thoughts about the images??

As I edited the full question, please note that this file will only be used in iphone,
I am doing the landscape view now i will do the portrait later on (only editing the right propertie of .visible)

Comment: why can't i offer a bountie for this question?

Comment: Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty. Now i know :(

Comment: Hey Toni, I don't understand ysour issue. What's the point you're desprerately trying to solve?

Comment: hey! thanks for your interest, check my edit so you can see how i see it on the phone (compare with firefox or chrome)

Comment: If anyone wants to take a stab at this, I made a jsfiddle with the relevant code before deciding I would rather watch the daily show:

http://jsfiddle.net/6b2Z6/

Comment: @Parker Ault: Tanks for the jsdfiddle but I updated the code -pretty much completely-

Answer (score 2):

use mediaqueries to detect orientation

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px)
{
    body {display: none;}
}

/* Landscape */
@media screen and (min-width: 321px)
{
    body {display: none;}
}
```

combined with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: And about how to make the <li> to have that bg images? what do you suggest? spliting in two or better to use the whole image somehow?

Comment: if i use only your portrait expreseion in iphone the body is NEVER visible, if I use only the landscape expression the body is allways visible; if I use both; the body is never visible.... (iphone4)